# Sleeping temperature when suffering from cold

Tags: sleep, common-cold, body-temperature

I usually sleep at around 69°F(20.6°C). If the temperature is anything above 71°F(21.7°C), I find it very difficult to fall asleep with my body burning up and all. However, when I am suffering from cold with a strep throat, runny nose, mild headache and general chills, I can easily fall asleep around 74°F(23.3°C). What is the explanation behind my body not burning up at those temperatures?

Comment: "general chills"

Comment: What exactly is my body going through when I am experiencing "general chills"?

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE. If you haven't done so yet, feel free to visit the [tour]. Have you tried googling for an answer? If so, what have you found?  Is there anything you don't quite understand?

Comment: You could easily fall asleep at 28 degree Celsius (78F) too, [as that’s the recommended minimum temperature for most AirCons](https://www.networx.com/article/the-best-ac-temperature-stay-cool-and). As a cold is usually accompanied with fever [(which doesn’t need to be treated as long as the temperature is below 38.9C or 102F)](https://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/fever/in-depth/fever/art-20050997) and your body heats up to that and wants to heat up to that, you probably won’t have trouble sleeping at 80 or 90F either.

Comment: Your question about chills needs to be a new question. It's actually a good one, so I encourage you to ask it.

Comment: @Narusan I grew up in in a tropical climate with no air conditioning, so it's not like I'm unfamiliar with heat, but today I live in a temperate climate and sleeping in 78F would be very uncomfortable for me. The source you cite for that is devoted to energy saving, not comfort. I doubt most people outside of tropical climates would find 78F comfortable.

Comment: @CareyGregory During my stay in Japan - which is far from tropical - the air conditioning was set to 28 degrees (outside had about 35), and no one I knew from any climate zones had trouble sleeping. // My main point was  that if you have fever (38 degrees temperature or so), anything below will be perceived as cool.

Comment: @Narusan: The normal body temperature is 37. According to your previous statement, I should still have no problem sleeping in any temperature below 37 even when I'm not sick. I'm not saying I can't sleep but it is very uncomfortable to sleep in any temperature above 22 when I'm not sick. So, I guess my question is, even though my body is burning up with fever, how am I still able to go to bed (comfortably) in a higher than my usual room temperature?

Comment: @AnjilDhamala Yeah, touché.